# cannot modify a DIV once click button

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova application, i want just Modify a DIV  when click on a button
but when the emulator starts, nothing happens
I used the code snipped to be more specific
here the code:

```js
var app = {

    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function () {

    
            var info = $('#info'),
                icon = $('#icon'),
                result;

                info.html('could not load weather');
                return;
            }
};

app.initialize();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Weather</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <img src="" id="icon">
      <div id="info">Loading...</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the output of the console? Is the google url whitelisten? It is better to load jquery local, so your user don't need an internet connection.

Comment: in javscript console appears this message:
cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.